# Java 9 и Android будет ли миру?

Tags: java, android

Не так давно официально состоялся релиз `Java 9 SE`. Принёс он с собой много новинок в плане функциональности, а также и скорости, вплоть до компилятора) Очень много чего в нём есть. Андроид же всё никак не перейдет на новую ступень развития `Java`, он еле-еле с 7 на 8 перебирается. Конечно есть котлин и всякое такое, у которого лозунг чуть ли не в 100 раз быстрее `Java`) Но я хочу `Java`) стоит ли её ждать вообще на  `Android`? Речь о 9-ой. Официальную позицию гугла не нашел. Да и вообще поиск искончался крахом, инфо об этом нету. Прошу строго не судить. Просто как `java` программиста меня это волнунет.

Comment: думаю, что не стоит ждать чуда, так как гугл начал использовать котлин

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych  вообщето гугл не использует котлин а сделал его официально поддерживаемым языком )КОтлин и до этого использовали просто гуг типо сказал окей теперь это для вас официально )

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych с таким же успехом можно писать на Скала но он не в списке официально подерживаемых )\

Comment: Поддержка Java 9 в Android несомненно будет, но когда, насколько полная поддержка и с какой минимальной версии API - вопрос сложный, в любом случае рассчитывать на скорое появление не стоит. Так, поддержка Java 8 (релиз - март 2014) была добавлена в Android Nougat (релиз - август 2016) с некоторыми ограничениями. Соответственно Java 9 можно ждать где то в Android R

Comment: @pavlofff  да этого я и боляся)

Comment: Насчет компилятора - в Android своя VM (ART), соответственно и компилятор тоже.