# Почему андроид использует Java 8

Tags: android, java-8

Во всех мануалах используется Java 8, возможно ли писать под андроид используя Java версии выше 8?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ресурсы:

[Java 9 и Android будет ли миру?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730161/java-9-%D0%B8-android-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83)

Судя по различным ресурсам, на которых я полазил, увидел, что в android до сих пор не поддерживаются некоторые функции из java 8, и нормальная поддержка java 8 в android проявилась только в 2016 , после финального релиза 2014 года. А финальный релиз java 9 состоялся в 2018, думаю скоро поддержка начнется, а сейчас , вроде как нельзя пользоваться версиями выше 8.

UPD: Ну как скоро....

Comment: Это связанно с исками Oracle к Googl'у? Если да, то это объясняет ситуацию с kotlin.

Comment: Я тут почитал.... С 2010 по 2016 года сумма иска между Google и Oracle выросла до 8,8млрд$ , с 2014 по 2018 Google так долго предостовляла поддержку  java 8, возможно , что бы ее оттянуть, поскольку в 2017г Google подключил Kotlin вроде как стал одним из оффициальных языков android

Comment: @user329672 , возможно как раз поэтому с этим и тянут